# Number of ways of drawing and numbering balls from an urn

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have an urn with $n$ balls. We draw $k$ distinguishable balls from the urn without replacement. After drawing the $k$ balls, we write a randomly chosen number from $1$ to $10$ on each ball. In how many ways can we obtain the $k$ balls with all possible numberings?

By definition, there are $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$ ways of picking $k$ balls from the urn. There are $10^k$ ways of writing the numbers on the $k$ balls.

So, are there $\binom{n}{k} 10^k$ ways to obtain the $k$ balls with all possible numberings?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not clear.  Prior to the numbering, are the balls distinct?  Usually, in these urn/ball problems, the balls are indistinguishable.

Comment: Yes, the balls are indistinguishable before the numbering.

Comment: Ok, so what does $\binom nk$ mean here?  There's only one way to extract $k$ balls, since we can't tell one selection from another.  Neither can we put our $k$ balls in order, so the $10^k$ is similarly wrong.

Comment: think of it this way:  in the end, all that matters is how many $1's$, $2's$, etc. do you have.  That is to say, you want to know how many solutions there  are to $a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{10}=k$ there are in non-negative integers.  That is a well known problem...

Comment: Note: your answer would be correct if you were choosing from $n$ *distinct* balls.  But you aren't.

Comment: Ah! I think I misunderstood your first question while trying to simplify the problem. The balls are actually distinguishable. (sorry for the confusion!)

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Anyway, as I said, if the balls were distinct, pre-numbering, then your answer is correct.

Comment: Updated. Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear to me. You have drawn k distinguishable balls (say by color). You have randomly given them numbers from $1-10$ Now, apparently you are forgetting about their distinguishability, and focusing only on numbers. Finally, how do you now **obtain** the $k$ balls with all possible numberings ?? You have already drawn and numbered. Please clarify. Is it a real problem ? Did you just make it up ? What happens to color $\equiv$ distinguishability ? What about the $n-k$ balls not drawn ? What about all colors not drawn ?